# Rotating Feature-Linked Annotation to MapLogic map book data frame rotation?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, annotation, maplogic

Once creating a feature-linked Annotation feature class, how do I set the rotation for the annotations to be horizontal with the data frame's rotation in a MapLogic map book?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend generating the annotation with the rotation correct for the page in the first place.  In ArcGIS 10.0 or higher, you can do this by feeding index polygons for the pages with a rotation field through the [Tiled Labels to Annotation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//007000000007000000) tool. Annotation for each page will be generated separately, with rotation taken into account if a rotation field is set, and tagged with the page it corresponds to.

Comment: While the Tiled Labels to Annotation tool worked, I'm running into another problem now with the Angle field not updating for the feature-linked annotations made with the tool.See: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73773/feature-linked-annotation-angle-field-error-arcgis-10-1