# Feature-linked Annotation Angle field error: ArcGIS 10.1

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, annotation, file-geodatabase

After running the "tiled labels to annotation" tool to get feature-linked annotations with the correct rotation angle for each label per frame, a small handful of the annotations will not take updates to the Angle field, a field generated by the tiled annotation field when it originally created the feature-linked annotations. I'm able to rotate the text in the label, but neither the border of the leader line will not rotate nor the base point of the leader will rotate/move.

This is an issue because it creates inconsistent label formats. (see screenshot below for an example of the problem leader border. The actual text of the label has already been rotated using the rotate tool for this example. Top of screenshot is rotated with the frame. The second screenshot is of a label whose Angle field updated correctly, and is placed correctly.)

[image: Problem feature-linked annotation]

[image: Correct feature-linked annotation]

I've tried to delete the problem annotations, reselect the features for these deleted annotations, and "Annotate Selected Features...", but the Angle field still will not update, which results in a label not rotated with the frame rotation.

Short of rerunning the entire feature class with tiled annotation, has anyone ever come across this problem within ArcMap and know of a solution?

Note: The feature-linked annotations were created with the tiled labels to annotation tool within ArcMap 10.1 and were created from a feature class within a gdb.

---

ADDITION:
The Angle field for these erroneous feature-linked annotations is "0", and when I try to manually update them from the attribute table, with the Field Calculator, or the Attributes tab in the Editor toolbar, I get this error message.

[image: error_message]

---

ADDITION 2:

"Edit Baseline Sketch" is not an option for these problem annotations, so I would guess that means they don't have curved baselines. The screenshot is of this option being unavailable for the annotation. I also tried changing it from the Annotations Edit Menu under Context Menus with no success.

Each annotation leader is stuck at Angle = 0 (which means the leader never rotates with my frames; the leaders are always pointing to Data Frame rotation = 0.)

[image]

Comment: Can you check to see if these particular annotation features have "curved" baselines (meaning, do they have more than 2 vertices?).  You can use the annotation edit tools context menu to show the geometries via "Edit Baseline Sketch".

Comment: The anno were generated from a point file, so there's no "follow-feature" option if that's what you mean? There's a "VerticalAlignment" field that's set = "Baseline"

Comment: Ok, but based on the images it appears to me that the text has a curved baseline which makes setting an angle invalid.  Try using the "Edit Annotation Tool" and its context menu to make the annotation "Straight" and then apply the angle.

Comment: You would think, but "Edit Baseline Sketch" is not an option for these annotations, and trying to make the change through "Curvature" also does not work (the Horizontal, Straight and Curved options are all non-selectable). (See ADDITION 2)

Answer (score 3):

I overcame this problem by running a data driven page definition query. Ensure that you add a field to your annotation feature class that has the page number/reference of that used in the map book/data driven pages.

You can then make the link. Before doing this though you must use the geoprocessing tool 'intersect' between your map series feature class and your annotations. This will then create features for each page in the map series. Populate the angle field in your annotations feature class with the corresponding 'rotation' field of the DDP or map book.

Once you run the DDP def. query the rotation problem will be solved.

Comment: Already have a similar setup, but instead of DDP I'm using MapLogic to run my pages. It's not an error with overlapping annotation from another page, because all of my other annotations rotate perfectly with the frame (which have a def query set to show their respective annotations for that page)